# R: create a vector iteratively out of named vectors

Tags: r

I have the following (character) vectors, that I want to merge in bigger vectors with the year content

```
text_2020_0001
text_2020_0002
...
text_2020_0320

text_2021_0001
text_2021_0002
...
text_2021_0237
```

What I want to get is

```
text_2020 <- c(text_2020_0001,text_2020_0002,...,text_2020_0320)
text_2021 <- c(text_2021_0001,text_2021_0002,...,text_2021_0237)
```

I have coded this double loop, that doesn't work, because c(paste0(), ...) is not the way to go, but I can't figure out what I should use.

```
for (i c(20,21)) {
    assign(paste0("text_20",i),
           paste0("text_20",i,"_0001"))
  for(j in (1,400) {
    assign(paste0("text_20",i),
           c(paste0("text_20",i),paste0("text_20",i,"_",formatC(j+1,width = 3, format = "d", flag = "0"))))
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the object names with `sprintf`

```
txt1 <- sprintf('text_%d_%04d', rep(c(2020, 2021), c(320, 237)), c(1:320, 1:237))
```

-output

```
> head(txt1)
[1] "text_2020_0001" "text_2020_0002" "text_2020_0003" "text_2020_0004" "text_2020_0005" "text_2020_0006"
> tail(txt1)
[1] "text_2021_0232" "text_2021_0233" "text_2021_0234" "text_2021_0235" "text_2021_0236" "text_2021_0237"
```

---

If it needs to be separate

```
txt2020 <- sprintf('text_2020_%04d', 1:320)
txt2021 <- sprintf('text_2021_%04d', 1:237)
```

If these are objects created in the global environment (not recommended), we can load those objects with `mget`

```
txt2020_out <- unlist(mget(txt2020), use.names = FALSE)
txt2021_out <- unlist(mget(txt2021), use.names = FALSE)
```

---

Also, these objects can be automatically loaded with a regex `pattern` in `ls` + `mget` into a `list`

```
txt2020_out <- unlist(mget(ls(pattern = 'text_2020_\\d{4}')), use.names = FALSE)
txt2021_out <- unlist(mget(ls(pattern = 'text_2021_\\d{4}')), use.names = FALSE)
```